# Finding Trigonometric Integration $\int\frac{\sin^8 x+\cos^9 x}{1+\tan^9 x}dx$

Tags: integration

> Finding $\displaystyle \int\frac{\sin^8 x+\cos^9 x}{1+\tan^9 x}dx$

$\bf{Attempt:}$ Integral $\displaystyle I = \int\frac{(\sin^8 x+\cos^9 x)}{\sin^9 x+\cos^9 x}\cdot \cos^9 xdx $

Put $(\sin^9 x+\cos^9 x) = t,$ then $9\sin x\cos x(\sin^7 x+\cos^7 x)dx = dt$

Could some help me how to solve it, Thanks

Comment: This looks to be a monster (assuming no typo in the exponents) !

Comment: WolframAlpha produces an exact answer and it is a **mess**...

Answer (score 2):

I am almost sure that there is a typo in the problem which is probably
$$\int\frac{\sin^\color{red}{9} (x)+\cos^9 (x)}{1+\tan^9 (x)}\,dx=\int \cos^9 (x)\,dx $$ which is simple using linear combinations of $\cos(nx)$ when $n$ is odd
$$\cos^9(x)=\frac{63 }{128}\cos (x)+\frac{21}{64} \cos (3 x)+\frac{9}{64} \cos (5 x)+\frac{9}{256}
   \cos (7 x)+\frac{1}{256} \cos (9 x)$$ Otherwise, as Benjamin Dickman  commented, it is a pure mess !

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{aligned} \int\frac{\sin^\color{red}{9} (x)+\cos^9 (x)}{1+\tan^9 (x)}\,dx=&\int \cos^9 x\,dx
\\= & \int\left(1-\sin ^2 x\right)^4 d(\sin x) \\
= & \int\left(1-4 \sin ^2 x+6 \sin ^4 x-4 \sin ^6 x+\sin ^2 x\right)  d(\sin x) \\
= & \sin x-\frac{4 \sin ^3 x}{3}+\frac{6 \sin ^5 x}{5}-\frac{4 \sin ^7 x}{7} +  \frac{\sin ^2 x}{9}+C
\end{aligned}
$$